# Is there a way to denote a repeated operation?

Tags: definition, function-and-relation-composition

For instance, if you have say:

```
4 + x = 10
```

We instantly calculate 10 - 4 to derive x, which is 6. So you could say there is only 1 operation, subtraction, where 4 is subtracted from 10. As simple as this seems however, you can't just 'magically' subtract 4 from 10, you have to do so step by step, i.e in increments of 1.

Is there a way to denote this? Something I had in mind was:

```
10 - 1 ... -4 = x
```

Or more generally, where a and b are known constants, and x is the unknown:

```
a + b = x
x - 1 ... -a = b
x - 1 ... -b = a
```

Where -1 ... -a means that you subtract 1 until you reach a, so all in all you subtract a total of a.

Comment: What you're looking for is recursion.

Comment: @mrp IDK. If you're not trying to study the process of how things repeat as an object in its own right, sometimes the simplicity of "it repeats this many times" is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Something like $$ x -\underbrace{1 - \ldots -1 }_{4 \text{ times}} $$ is how I've always seen it.

Answer (score 0):

Let

$$u (x) := x+1 \qquad \qquad d (x) := x-1$$

and

$$f^{(n)} := f \circ f^{(n-1)} \qquad \qquad f^{(0)} := \mbox{id}$$

Hence, if $a$ is a positive integer, then $d^{(a)} (a) = 0$. If $b$ is a negative integer, then $u^{(-b)} (b) = 0$.

---

In [Haskell](http://tryhaskell.org/),

```
λ take 11 $ iterate (\x->x-1) 10 
[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]
```

Comment: Sorry I really don't follow, i've been trying to understand everything you've wrote, but I can't grasp it.

Comment: @user2901512 Do you know what function composition is? Note that $$d^{(2)} (2) = (d \circ d) (2) = d (d(2)) = d(1) = 0$$

Comment: What happened to the n-1 though? So wouldn't it be d*d^(n-1)*2?

Comment: @user2901512 That is the definition of $f^{(n)}$.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be d*d^(2-1)*2 then?

Comment: @user2901512 $$d^{(5)} (5) = d^{(4)} (4) = d^{(3)} (3) = d^{(2)} (2) = d (1) = 0$$

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. One more thing, when you say that f^(n) = ..., do you mean f(n)? I mean, f^n is of course already defined, and when dealing with composite functions, the pre-defined meaning of f^n isn't a function... so it's kinda throwing me off.

Comment: @user2901512 I am using the definition $f^{(2)} := f \circ f$, $f^{(3)} := f \circ f \circ f$, etc. Some use the notation $f^2 := f \circ f$, but one could read $f^2$ as the square of $f$, rather than the composition of $f$ with itself.

Comment: Seriously? Haskell code? I appreciate Haskell as much as anyone, but how is this an appropriate answer? If I wrote "And then we have to subtract 1 from n 20 times. Or as they say in Haskell, iterate (-1) n !! 20" in any kind of math context, I'd be appropriately laughed at. OP needs a hammer, not factory equipment that can drive 10,000 nails per hour.

Comment: @MikeHaskel What hammer is that?

Comment: @MikeHaskel am gonna be honest, you make Haskell sound very attractive :D